# Curve text on existing circle

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, math, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

For an application I am building I have drawn 2 circles. One a bit bigger than the other. I want to curve text between those lines, for a circular menu I am building.

I read most stuff about curving a text that you have to split up your text in characters and draw each character on it's own with the right angle in mind (by rotating the context you are drawing on).

I just can't wrap my head around on how to get the right angles and positions for my characters.

I included a screenshot on what the menu, at the moment, look like. Only the texts I added by are loaded from an image in an UIImageView.

[image]

I hope someone can get me some starting points on how I can draw the text in the white circle, at certain points.

EDIT:
Ok, I am currently at this point:

[image]

I accomplish by using the following code:

```
- (UIImage*) createMenuRingWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    CGRect imageSize = CGRectMake(0,0,300,300);
    float perSectionDegrees = 360 / [sections count];
    float totalRotation = 90;
    char* fontName = (char*)[self.menuItemsFont.fontName cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, imageSize.size.width, imageSize.size.height, 8, 4 * imageSize.size.width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextSelectFont(context, fontName, 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);

    CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(imageSize.size.width / 2, imageSize.size.height / 2);
    double radius = (frame.size.width / 2);

    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(centerPoint.x - (frame.size.width / 2), centerPoint.y - (frame.size.height / 2), frame.size.width, frame.size.height));

    for (int index = 0; index < [sections count]; index++)
    {
        NSString* menuItemText = [sections objectAtIndex:index];
        CGSize textSize = [menuItemText sizeWithFont:self.menuItemsFont];
        char* menuItemTextChar = (char*)[menuItemText cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        float x = centerPoint.x + radius * cos(degreesToRadians(totalRotation));
        float y = centerPoint.y + radius * sin(degreesToRadians(totalRotation));

        CGContextSaveGState(context);

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, x, y);
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, degreesToRadians(totalRotation - 90));
        CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 0 - (textSize.width / 2), 0 - (textSize.height / 2), menuItemTextChar, strlen(menuItemTextChar));

        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        totalRotation += perSectionDegrees;
    }

    CGImageRef contextImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:contextImage];
}
```

These are the variables I use in there:

```
NSArray* sections = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"settings", @"test", @"stats", @"nog iets", @"woei", @"woei2", nil];
self.menuItemsFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"VAGRounded-Bold" size:18];
```

The rotation of the words seem correct, the placement also. Now I need somehow figure out at which rotation the letters (and their coordinates) should be. I could use some help with that.

**Edit:** Fixed! Check out the following code!

```
- (void) drawStringAtContext:(CGContextRef) context string:(NSString*) text atAngle:(float) angle withRadius:(float) radius
{
    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:self.menuItemsFont];

    float perimeter = 2 * M_PI * radius;
    float textAngle = textSize.width / perimeter * 2 * M_PI;

    angle += textAngle / 2;

    for (int index = 0; index < [text length]; index++)
    {
        NSRange range = {index, 1};
        NSString* letter = [text substringWithRange:range];     
        char* c = (char*)[letter cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        CGSize charSize = [letter sizeWithFont:self.menuItemsFont];

        NSLog(@"Char %@ with size: %f x %f", letter, charSize.width, charSize.height);

        float x = radius * cos(angle);
        float y = radius * sin(angle);

        float letterAngle = (charSize.width / perimeter * -2 * M_PI);

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, x, y);
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, (angle - 0.5 * M_PI));
        CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 0, 0, c, strlen(c));
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        angle += letterAngle;
    }
}

- (UIImage*) createMenuRingWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(frame.size.width / 2, frame.size.height / 2);
    char* fontName = (char*)[self.menuItemsFont.fontName cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    CGFloat* ringColorComponents = (float*)CGColorGetComponents(ringColor.CGColor);
    CGFloat* textColorComponents = (float*)CGColorGetComponents(textColor.CGColor);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, frame.size.width, frame.size.height, 8, 4 * frame.size.width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

    CGContextSelectFont(context, fontName, 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, ringColorComponents[0], ringColorComponents[1], ringColorComponents[2], ringAlpha);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, ringWidth);  

    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(ringWidth, ringWidth, frame.size.width - (ringWidth * 2), frame.size.height - (ringWidth * 2)));
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, textColorComponents[0], textColorComponents[1], textColorComponents[2], textAlpha);

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y);

    float angleStep = 2 * M_PI / [sections count];
    float angle = degreesToRadians(90);

    textRadius = textRadius - 12;

    for (NSString* text in sections)
    {
        [self drawStringAtContext:context string:text atAngle:angle withRadius:textRadius];
        angle -= angleStep;
    }

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGImageRef contextImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    [self saveImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:contextImage] withName:@"test.png"];
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:contextImage];

}
```

Comment: This approach worked well for me-- until I had to use special characters like the degree symbol and foreign diacriticals. Those characters were in the font I was using, so I guess it's an encoding issue? Changing NSASCIIStringEncoding didn't solve my problem, so I went with the CoreText solution (see below).

Comment: I tired to use this code, but ran into some issues, even using the Updated post.. for one, textRadius errors as Undefined. I'm guessing it's a float but not sure what it should start as. I was trying to draw a single string, so I didn't end up using it. Also many of the functions are now deprecated in IOS7.  If you are trying to use this and don't see any text on the screen, try using a different font.. Apparently VAGRounded-Bold is not a standard IOS font.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I tried to work it out quickly on paper, so i may be wrong :)

Convert the length of the string into units on the [UnitCircle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle). Thus (string.lenght/ circle perimeter)*2Pi. You now have the angle in radians for the whole string. (That is the angle between start and end of the string)

For the separate letters you could do the same to get the angle (in radians) for individual letters (using letter widths)

Once you have the angle in radians you can work out the x and y position (and rotation) of the letters.

**Bonus:** for even spacing you could even work out the ratio between the total length of all strings and the whole perimeter. And divide the remaining space equally between the string.

**Update**
I made a [proof of concept](http://bodewes.home.fmf.nl/stackoverflow/3841642/) using html5/canvas, so view it with a decent browser :) You should be able to port it. (mind you, the code isn't commented)
*wtf: the code runs fine with the chrome debug console open, and fails when it is closed. (workaround: open chrome console: ctrl-shift-j and reload the page: f5); FF3.6.8 seems to do fine, but the letters 'dance'.*

Comment: I am not that much of a math wonder. But I am missing something I believe. I divided my string in characters and I know the width+height of those, but how do I know at which angle they should be placed? I took your formula's and incorporated them in the code, but the angle isn't actually dependent on the location it seems?
I suck at this ;)

Comment: I didn't add any calculations for the orientation of the characters (yet) First orde is to get the position right (try it with dots) Then get the orientation right. The baseline of the characters is orthogonal to the angle

Comment: Thank you Dribbel for providing me with the solution. I will update my post shortly to provide the answer

Answer (score 31):

I adapted Apple's CoreTextArcCocoa sample project (mentioned by Tom H in [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841642/curve-text-on-existing-circle/3855776#3855776)) and thought I'd share it here.

I added a few other features as well, such as the ability to set the arc size to something smaller than 180, and the text color and offset shift as properties (so that you don't have to have a huge frame to show the whole text).

```
 /*

 File: CoreTextArcView.m (iOS version)

 Abstract: Defines and implements the CoreTextArcView custom UIView subclass to
 draw text on a curve and illustrate best practices with CoreText.

 Based on CoreTextArcView provided by Apple for Mac OS X https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreTextArcCocoa/Introduction/Intro.html

 Ported to iOS (& added color, arcsize features) August 2011 by Alec Vance, Juggleware LLC http://juggleware.com/

 */ 

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>


@interface CoreTextArcView : UIView {
@private
    UIFont *            _font;
    NSString *          _string;
    CGFloat             _radius;
    UIColor *           _color;
    CGFloat             _arcSize;
    CGFloat             _shiftH, _shiftV; // horiz & vertical shift

    struct {
        unsigned int    showsGlyphBounds:1;
        unsigned int    showsLineMetrics:1;
        unsigned int    dimsSubstitutedGlyphs:1;
        unsigned int    reserved:29;
    }                   _flags;
}

@property(retain, nonatomic) UIFont *font;
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSString *text;
@property(readonly, nonatomic) NSAttributedString *attributedString;
@property(assign, nonatomic) CGFloat radius;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL showsGlyphBounds;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL showsLineMetrics;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL dimsSubstitutedGlyphs;
@property(retain, nonatomic) UIColor *color;
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat arcSize;
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat shiftH, shiftV;
@end


/*

 File: CoreTextArcView.m (iOS version)

 */ 

#import "CoreTextArcView.h"
#import <AssertMacros.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#define ARCVIEW_DEBUG_MODE          NO

#define ARCVIEW_DEFAULT_FONT_NAME   @"Helvetica"
#define ARCVIEW_DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE   64.0
#define ARCVIEW_DEFAULT_RADIUS      150.0
#define ARCVIEW_DEFAULT_ARC_SIZE    180.0



@implementation CoreTextArcView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:ARCVIEW_DEFAULT_FONT_NAME size:ARCVIEW_DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE];
        self.text = @"Curvaceous Type";
        self.radius = ARCVIEW_DEFAULT_RADIUS;
        self.showsGlyphBounds = NO;
        self.showsLineMetrics = NO;
        self.dimsSubstitutedGlyphs = NO;
        self.color = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.arcSize = ARCVIEW_DEFAULT_ARC_SIZE;
        self.shiftH = self.shiftV = 0.0f;
    }
    return self;
}

typedef struct GlyphArcInfo {
    CGFloat         width;
    CGFloat         angle;  // in radians
} GlyphArcInfo;

static void PrepareGlyphArcInfo(CTLineRef line, CFIndex glyphCount, GlyphArcInfo *glyphArcInfo, CGFloat arcSizeRad)
{
    NSArray *runArray = (NSArray *)CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line);

    // Examine each run in the line, updating glyphOffset to track how far along the run is in terms of glyphCount.
    CFIndex glyphOffset = 0;
    for (id run in runArray) {
        CFIndex runGlyphCount = CTRunGetGlyphCount((CTRunRef)run);

        // Ask for the width of each glyph in turn.
        CFIndex runGlyphIndex = 0;
        for (; runGlyphIndex < runGlyphCount; runGlyphIndex++) {
            glyphArcInfo[runGlyphIndex + glyphOffset].width = CTRunGetTypographicBounds((CTRunRef)run, CFRangeMake(runGlyphIndex, 1), NULL, NULL, NULL);
        }

        glyphOffset += runGlyphCount;
    }

    double lineLength = CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    CGFloat prevHalfWidth = glyphArcInfo[0].width / 2.0;
    glyphArcInfo[0].angle = (prevHalfWidth / lineLength) * arcSizeRad;

    // Divide the arc into slices such that each one covers the distance from one glyph's center to the next.
    CFIndex lineGlyphIndex = 1;
    for (; lineGlyphIndex < glyphCount; lineGlyphIndex++) {
        CGFloat halfWidth = glyphArcInfo[lineGlyphIndex].width / 2.0;
        CGFloat prevCenterToCenter = prevHalfWidth + halfWidth;

        glyphArcInfo[lineGlyphIndex].angle = (prevCenterToCenter / lineLength) * arcSizeRad;

        prevHalfWidth = halfWidth;
    }
}


// ensure that redraw occurs.
-(void)setText:(NSString *)text{
    [_string release];
    _string = [text retain];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

//set arc size in degrees (180 = half circle)
-(void)setArcSize:(CGFloat)degrees{
    _arcSize = degrees * M_PI/180.0;
}

//get arc size in degrees
-(CGFloat)arcSize{
    return _arcSize * 180.0/M_PI;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Don't draw if we don't have a font or string
    if (self.font == NULL || self.text == NULL) 
        return;

    // Initialize the text matrix to a known value
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    //Reset the transformation
    //Doing this means you have to reset the contentScaleFactor to 1.0
    CGAffineTransform t0 = CGContextGetCTM(context);


    CGFloat xScaleFactor = t0.a > 0 ? t0.a : -t0.a;
    CGFloat yScaleFactor = t0.d > 0 ? t0.d : -t0.d;
    t0 = CGAffineTransformInvert(t0);
    if (xScaleFactor != 1.0 || yScaleFactor != 1.0)
        t0 = CGAffineTransformScale(t0, xScaleFactor, yScaleFactor);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, t0);

    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

    if(ARCVIEW_DEBUG_MODE){
        // Draw a black background (debug)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(context, self.layer.bounds);
    }

    NSAttributedString *attStr = self.attributedString;
    CFAttributedStringRef asr = (CFAttributedStringRef)attStr;
    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(asr);
    assert(line != NULL);

    CFIndex glyphCount = CTLineGetGlyphCount(line);
    if (glyphCount == 0) {
        CFRelease(line);
        return;
    }

    GlyphArcInfo *  glyphArcInfo = (GlyphArcInfo*)calloc(glyphCount, sizeof(GlyphArcInfo));
    PrepareGlyphArcInfo(line, glyphCount, glyphArcInfo, _arcSize);

    // Move the origin from the lower left of the view nearer to its center.
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMidX(rect)+_shiftH, CGRectGetMidY(rect)+_shiftV - self.radius / 2.0);

    if(ARCVIEW_DEBUG_MODE){
        // Stroke the arc in red for verification.
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextAddArc(context, 0.0, 0.0, self.radius, M_PI_2+_arcSize/2.0, M_PI_2-_arcSize/2.0, 1);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }

    // Rotate the context 90 degrees counterclockwise (per 180 degrees)
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, _arcSize/2.0);

    // Now for the actual drawing. The angle offset for each glyph relative to the previous glyph has already been calculated; with that information in hand, draw those glyphs overstruck and centered over one another, making sure to rotate the context after each glyph so the glyphs are spread along a semicircular path.

    CGPoint textPosition = CGPointMake(0.0, self.radius);
    CGContextSetTextPosition(context, textPosition.x, textPosition.y);

    CFArrayRef runArray = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line);
    CFIndex runCount = CFArrayGetCount(runArray);

    CFIndex glyphOffset = 0;
    CFIndex runIndex = 0;
    for (; runIndex < runCount; runIndex++) {
        CTRunRef run = (CTRunRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(runArray, runIndex);
        CFIndex runGlyphCount = CTRunGetGlyphCount(run);
        Boolean drawSubstitutedGlyphsManually = false;
        CTFontRef runFont = CFDictionaryGetValue(CTRunGetAttributes(run), kCTFontAttributeName);

        // Determine if we need to draw substituted glyphs manually. Do so if the runFont is not the same as the overall font.
        if (self.dimsSubstitutedGlyphs && ![self.font isEqual:(UIFont *)runFont]) {
            drawSubstitutedGlyphsManually = true;
        }

        CFIndex runGlyphIndex = 0;
        for (; runGlyphIndex < runGlyphCount; runGlyphIndex++) {
            CFRange glyphRange = CFRangeMake(runGlyphIndex, 1);
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, -(glyphArcInfo[runGlyphIndex + glyphOffset].angle));

            // Center this glyph by moving left by half its width.
            CGFloat glyphWidth = glyphArcInfo[runGlyphIndex + glyphOffset].width;
            CGFloat halfGlyphWidth = glyphWidth / 2.0;
            CGPoint positionForThisGlyph = CGPointMake(textPosition.x - halfGlyphWidth, textPosition.y);

            // Glyphs are positioned relative to the text position for the line, so offset text position leftwards by this glyph's width in preparation for the next glyph.
            textPosition.x -= glyphWidth;

            CGAffineTransform textMatrix = CTRunGetTextMatrix(run);
            textMatrix.tx = positionForThisGlyph.x;
            textMatrix.ty = positionForThisGlyph.y;
            CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, textMatrix);

            if (!drawSubstitutedGlyphsManually) {
                CTRunDraw(run, context, glyphRange);
            } 
            else {
                // We need to draw the glyphs manually in this case because we are effectively applying a graphics operation by setting the context fill color. Normally we would use kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, but this does not apply as we don't know the ranges for the colors in advance, and we wanted demonstrate how to manually draw.
                CGFontRef cgFont = CTFontCopyGraphicsFont(runFont, NULL);
                CGGlyph glyph;
                CGPoint position;

                CTRunGetGlyphs(run, glyphRange, &glyph);
                CTRunGetPositions(run, glyphRange, &position);

                CGContextSetFont(context, cgFont);
                CGContextSetFontSize(context, CTFontGetSize(runFont));
                CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.5);
                CGContextShowGlyphsAtPositions(context, &glyph, &position, 1);

                CFRelease(cgFont);
            }

            // Draw the glyph bounds 
            if ((self.showsGlyphBounds) != 0) {
                CGRect glyphBounds = CTRunGetImageBounds(run, context, glyphRange);

                CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                CGContextStrokeRect(context, glyphBounds);
            }
            // Draw the bounding boxes defined by the line metrics
            if ((self.showsLineMetrics) != 0) {
                CGRect lineMetrics;
                CGFloat ascent, descent;

                CTRunGetTypographicBounds(run, glyphRange, &ascent, &descent, NULL);

                // The glyph is centered around the y-axis
                lineMetrics.origin.x = -halfGlyphWidth;
                lineMetrics.origin.y = positionForThisGlyph.y - descent;
                lineMetrics.size.width = glyphWidth; 
                lineMetrics.size.height = ascent + descent;

                CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                CGContextStrokeRect(context, lineMetrics);
            }
        }

        glyphOffset += runGlyphCount;
    }

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    free(glyphArcInfo);
    CFRelease(line);    



}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [_font release];
    [_string release];
    [_color release];
    [super dealloc]
}

@synthesize font = _font;
@synthesize text = _string;
@synthesize radius = _radius;
@synthesize color = _color;
@synthesize arcSize = _arcSize;
@synthesize shiftH = _shiftH;
@synthesize shiftV = _shiftV;

@dynamic attributedString;
- (NSAttributedString *)attributedString {
    // Create an attributed string with the current font and string.
    assert(self.font != nil);
    assert(self.text != nil);

    // Create our attributes...

    // font
    CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)self.font.fontName, self.font.pointSize, NULL);

    // color
    CGColorRef colorRef = self.color.CGColor;

    // pack it into attributes dictionary

    NSDictionary *attributesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    (id)fontRef, (id)kCTFontAttributeName,
                                    colorRef, (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                    nil];
    assert(attributesDict != nil);


    // Create the attributed string
    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text attributes:attributesDict];

    CFRelease(fontRef);

    return [attrString autorelease];
}

@dynamic showsGlyphBounds;
- (BOOL)showsGlyphBounds {
    return _flags.showsGlyphBounds;
}

- (void)setShowsGlyphBounds:(BOOL)show {
    _flags.showsGlyphBounds = show ? 1 : 0;
}

@dynamic showsLineMetrics;
- (BOOL)showsLineMetrics {
    return _flags.showsLineMetrics;
}

- (void)setShowsLineMetrics:(BOOL)show {
    _flags.showsLineMetrics = show ? 1 : 0;
}

@dynamic dimsSubstitutedGlyphs;
- (BOOL)dimsSubstitutedGlyphs {
    return _flags.dimsSubstitutedGlyphs;
}

- (void)setDimsSubstitutedGlyphs:(BOOL)dim {
    _flags.dimsSubstitutedGlyphs = dim ? 1 : 0;
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm using this code in one of my own projects, and I noticed it didn't contain a dealloc, so I'm pasting it below. Also Instruments is reporting 2 other memory leaks: 1) from drawRect and 2) from the call to attributedString. On the latter it has the necessary autorelease on return so I am not sure why it's leaking. If anyone figures either of these out I'd be grateful.
-(void)dealloc{
    [_font release];
    [_string release];
    [_color release];
    
    
    [super dealloc];

Comment: Thanks for this! working nicely. What do I need to modify to enable inverted arc? (means "Smiling" instead of "crying")

Comment: @juggleware You can always edit your own posts. I'll make a quick edit adding your `-dealloc`. Leak in `-attributedString` is lack of release for `fontRef`; I'll add that too. I can't figure out what the bug in `drawRect:` is, and clang static analyzer doesn't help.

Comment: Tx a lot for this great sample code. It works for me but I would like to use different colors for the text (1 word red, another green). I would like also to choose where in the circle the text will start. Is it possible for you to give advice for those 2 features and/or create a github for this great code ?

Comment: Incase anybody will need the same effect as Avraham Shukron, you have to setArcSize or setArcRadius negative. Thats the way to make arc "Smiling" instead of "crying".

Comment: @juggleware Can you put this on Github?

Comment: You got it @yourfriendzak, it's on github now: https://github.com/juggleware/CoreTextArcView_iOS I'm looking forward to seeing what you add to it!

Comment: Hmmm it works great but the text is shifted vertically ... i.e. the center is not exactly at the frame center but below it (by some 100 pixels) so the lower part of the text is not shown... Anyone has the same issue?

Comment: @Michael, did you try setting the shiftV property?

Comment: Hi @juggleware,

Thanks for the awesome code! somehow i couldn't get it working properly. i got a backbox for it.

i import it and initWithFrame and addSubview

Answer (score 7):

To save you some time,
here is what i've found for the CoreTextArcView that exposes

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame font:(UIFont *)font text:(NSString *)text radius:(float)radius arcSize:(float)arcSize color:(UIColor *)color;
```

```
  (x,y)<---------------     w             --------------->
      +--------------------------------------------------+
     ^|                                                  |  <--
     ||                                                  |  frame
     ||                                                  |
     ||                 VED L A BEL                      |
     ||             CU R            HE                   |
     ||           xx                   RE  x             |
      |          xx                        xxx           |
      |        xxx xx                     x   xxx        |
    h |      xxx    xx                  xxx     xx       |
      |      x       xxx         <-----------------------------
      |     xx         xx   xxxxxxx   xx           x     |  arcSize :
     ||    xx            xxx       xxx             xx    |  opening angle
     ||    x              xxx      xx               x    |  in degrees
     ||   xx                xx  xxx                 x    |
     ||   x  <---- r  ----->   x                    x    |
     ||   x                      (xc,yc)            x    |
     ||   x                             <-----------------------
     ||   x                                        xx    |  xc = x + w /2
     v+---xx--------------------------------------xx-----+  yc = y + h /2 + r /2
           xx                                    xx
            x                                   xx
            xxx                                xx
              xxx                            xxx
                xxxx                      xxxx
                   xxxxx              xxxxx
                        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

this is valid for r > 0 and arcsize > 0.

Answer (score 7):

This is my method to draw curved attributed strings on layers, at a predefined angle (in radians):

```
[self drawCurvedStringOnLayer:self.layer withAttributedText:incident atAngle:angle withRadius:300];
```

The string is also automatically reversed on the bottom area of the arc.

[image]

```
- (void)drawCurvedStringOnLayer:(CALayer *)layer
             withAttributedText:(NSAttributedString *)text
                        atAngle:(float)angle
                     withRadius:(float)radius {

    // angle in radians

    CGSize textSize = CGRectIntegral([text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                        options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                        context:nil]).size;

    float perimeter = 2 * M_PI * radius;
    float textAngle = (textSize.width / perimeter * 2 * M_PI); 

    float textRotation;
    float textDirection;
    if (angle > degreesToRadians(10) && angle < degreesToRadians(170)) {
        //bottom string
        textRotation = 0.5 * M_PI ;
        textDirection = - 2 * M_PI;
        angle += textAngle / 2;
    } else {
        //top string
        textRotation = 1.5 * M_PI ;
        textDirection = 2 * M_PI;
        angle -= textAngle / 2;
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < text.length; c++) {
        NSRange range = {c, 1};
        NSAttributedString* letter = [text attributedSubstringFromRange:range];
        CGSize charSize = CGRectIntegral([letter boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                              options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                              context:nil]).size;

        float letterAngle = ( (charSize.width / perimeter) * textDirection );

        float x = radius * cos(angle + (letterAngle/2));
        float y = radius * sin(angle + (letterAngle/2));

        CATextLayer *singleChar = [self drawTextOnLayer:layer
                                           withText:letter
                                              frame:CGRectMake(layer.frame.size.width/2 - charSize.width/2 + x,
                                                               layer.frame.size.height/2 - charSize.height/2 + y,
                                                               charSize.width, charSize.height)
                                            bgColor:nil
                                            opacity:1];

        singleChar.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform( CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle - textRotation) );

        angle += letterAngle;
    }
}


- (CATextLayer *)drawTextOnLayer:(CALayer *)layer
                        withText:(NSAttributedString *)text
                           frame:(CGRect)frame
                         bgColor:(UIColor *)bgColor
                         opacity:(float)opacity {

    CATextLayer *textLayer = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
    [textLayer setFrame:frame];
    [textLayer setString:text];
    [textLayer setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
    [textLayer setBackgroundColor:bgColor.CGColor];
    [textLayer setContentsScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
    [textLayer setOpacity:opacity];
    [layer addSublayer:textLayer];
    return textLayer;
}


/** Degrees to Radian **/
#define degreesToRadians(degrees) (( degrees ) / 180.0 * M_PI )

/** Radians to Degrees **/
#define radiansToDegrees(radians) (( radians ) * ( 180.0 / M_PI ) )
```

Comment: This was a great solution! There are a few changes for swift 3, mainly that everything should be CGFloat and the UIColor in `drawTextOnLayer` should be optional but otherwise the conversion was trivial.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code!
I did a swift 3 port here
https://gist.github.com/cemolcay/9525d28a203da83d333545fc6e0d4371

Answer (score 5):

Check out this Apple sample project:  [CoreTextArcCocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreTextArcCocoa/Introduction/Intro.html)

> Demonstrates using Core Text to draw
>   text along an arc in a Cocoa
>   application. As well, this sample
>   illustrates how you can use the Cocoa
>   font panel to receive font settings
>   that can be used by Core Text to
>   select the font used for drawing.

CoreText is also available in iOS so you *should* be able to implement something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But somehow I can not get that to work nicely. Either my text is way off posittion or it isn't appearing at all. I had it working for 4 menu items, and now I wanted to add a fifth item and then everything is borked again. I think I need some more help.

Comment: I added some more code to my post. Explaining where I stand at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the git project mentioned above, and as *ZpaceZombor* said , there is a wrong offset

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMidX(rect)+_shiftH, CGRectGetMidY(rect)+_shiftV - self.radius / 2.0);
```

I've changed simply to

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMidX(rect)+_shiftH, CGRectGetMidY(rect)+_shiftV);
```

I've set the radius to the Min value between width and height of the container view, so i've  set the arc size to **2π** .

I've arbitrary changed the line

```
CGContextRotateCTM(context, _arcSize/2.0);
```

with

```
CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI_2);
```

I've changed the init method to

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame font:(UIFont *)font text:(NSString *)text color:(UIColor *)color{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.font = font;
        self.text = text;
        self.radius = -1 * (frame.size.width > frame.size.height ? frame.size.height / 2 : frame.size.width / 2);
        _arcSize = 2* M_PI;
        self.showsGlyphBounds = NO;
        self.showsLineMetrics = NO;
        self.dimsSubstitutedGlyphs = NO;
        self.color = color;
        self.shiftH = self.shiftV = 0.0f;

    }
    return self;
}
```

After a lot of attempts, i've produce this modification to the function `PrepareGlyphArcInfo`

```
// this constants come from a single case ( fontSize = 22 | circle diameter = 250px | lower circle diameter 50px | 0.12f is a proportional acceptable value of 250px diameter | 0.18f is a proportional acceptable value of 50px | 0.035f is a proportional acceptable value of "big" chars
#define kReferredCharSpacing 0.12f
#define kReferredFontSize 22.f
#define kReferredMajorDiameter 250.f
#define kReferredMinorDiameter 50.f
#define kReferredMinorSpacingFix 0.18f
#define kReferredBigCharSpacingFix  0.035f

static void PrepareGlyphArcInfo(UIFont* font,CGFloat containerRadius,CTLineRef line, CFIndex glyphCount, GlyphArcInfo *glyphArcInfo, CGFloat arcSizeRad)
{
    NSArray *runArray = (NSArray *)CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line);

    CGFloat curMaxTypoWidth = 0.f;
    CGFloat curMinTypoWidth = 0.f;

    // Examine each run in the line, updating glyphOffset to track how far along the run is in terms of glyphCount.
    CFIndex glyphOffset = 0;
    for (id run in runArray) {
        CFIndex runGlyphCount = CTRunGetGlyphCount((CTRunRef)run);

            // Ask for the width of each glyph in turn.
        CFIndex runGlyphIndex = 0;
        for (; runGlyphIndex < runGlyphCount; runGlyphIndex++) {
            glyphArcInfo[runGlyphIndex + glyphOffset].width = CTRunGetTypographicBounds((CTRunRef)run, CFRangeMake(runGlyphIndex, 1), NULL, NULL, NULL);

            if (curMaxTypoWidth < glyphArcInfo[runGlyphIndex + glyphOffset].width)
                curMaxTypoWidth = glyphArcInfo[runGlyphIndex + glyphOffset].width;

            if (curMinTypoWidth > glyphArcInfo[runGlyphIndex + glyphOffset].width || curMinTypoWidth == 0)
                curMinTypoWidth = glyphArcInfo[runGlyphIndex + glyphOffset].width;

        }

        glyphOffset += runGlyphCount;
    }

    //double lineLength = CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    glyphArcInfo[0].angle = M_PI_2; // start at the bottom circle

    CFIndex lineGlyphIndex = 1;

    // based on font size. (supposing that with fontSize = 22 we could use 0.12)
    CGFloat maxCharSpacing = font.pointSize * kReferredCharSpacing / kReferredFontSize;

    // for diameter minor than referred 250
    if ((fabsf(containerRadius)*2) < kReferredMajorDiameter)
        maxCharSpacing = maxCharSpacing + kReferredMinorSpacingFix * kReferredMinorDiameter / (fabsf(containerRadius)*2);

    CGFloat startAngle = fabsf(glyphArcInfo[0].angle);
    CGFloat endAngle = startAngle;

    for (; lineGlyphIndex < glyphCount; lineGlyphIndex++) {

        CGFloat deltaWidth = curMaxTypoWidth - glyphArcInfo[lineGlyphIndex].width;

        // fix applied to large characters like uppercase letters or symbols
        CGFloat bigCharFix = (glyphArcInfo[lineGlyphIndex-1].width == curMaxTypoWidth || (glyphArcInfo[lineGlyphIndex-1].width+2) >= curMaxTypoWidth ? kReferredBigCharSpacingFix : 0 );

        glyphArcInfo[lineGlyphIndex].angle = - (maxCharSpacing * (glyphArcInfo[lineGlyphIndex].width + deltaWidth ) / curMaxTypoWidth) - bigCharFix;

        endAngle += fabsf(glyphArcInfo[lineGlyphIndex].angle);
    }

    // center text to bottom
    glyphArcInfo[0].angle = glyphArcInfo[0].angle + (endAngle - startAngle ) / 2;

}
```

And changed the `drawRect:` method to

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Don't draw if we don't have a font or string
    if (self.font == NULL || self.text == NULL) 
        return;

    // Initialize the text matrix to a known value
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //Reset the transformation
    //Doing this means you have to reset the contentScaleFactor to 1.0
    CGAffineTransform t0 = CGContextGetCTM(context);

    CGFloat xScaleFactor = t0.a > 0 ? t0.a : -t0.a;
    CGFloat yScaleFactor = t0.d > 0 ? t0.d : -t0.d;
    t0 = CGAffineTransformInvert(t0);
    if (xScaleFactor != 1.0 || yScaleFactor != 1.0)
        t0 = CGAffineTransformScale(t0, xScaleFactor, yScaleFactor);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, t0);

    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

    NSAttributedString *attStr = self.attributedString;
    CFAttributedStringRef asr = (CFAttributedStringRef)attStr;
    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(asr);
    assert(line != NULL);

    CFIndex glyphCount = CTLineGetGlyphCount(line);
    if (glyphCount == 0) {
        CFRelease(line);
        return;
    }

    GlyphArcInfo *  glyphArcInfo = (GlyphArcInfo*)calloc(glyphCount, sizeof(GlyphArcInfo));
    PrepareGlyphArcInfo(self.font, self.radius, line, glyphCount, glyphArcInfo, _arcSize);

    // Move the origin from the lower left of the view nearer to its center.
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMidX(rect)+_shiftH, CGRectGetMidY(rect)+_shiftV);

    if(ARCVIEW_DEBUG_MODE){
        // Stroke the arc in red for verification.
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextAddArc(context, 0.0, 0.0, self.radius, M_PI_2+_arcSize/2.0, M_PI_2-_arcSize/2.0, 1);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }

    // Rotate the context 90 degrees counterclockwise (per 180 degrees)
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI_2);

    // Now for the actual drawing. The angle offset for each glyph relative to the previous glyph has already been calculated; with that information in hand, draw those glyphs overstruck and centered over one another, making sure to rotate the context after each glyph so the glyphs are spread along a semicircular path.

    CGPoint textPosition = CGPointMake(0.0, self.radius);
    CGContextSetTextPosition(context, textPosition.x, textPosition.y);

    CFArrayRef runArray = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line);
    CFIndex runCount = CFArrayGetCount(runArray);

    CFIndex glyphOffset = 0;
    CFIndex runIndex = 0;
    for (; runIndex < runCount; runIndex++) {
        CTRunRef run = (CTRunRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(runArray, runIndex);
        CFIndex runGlyphCount = CTRunGetGlyphCount(run);
        Boolean drawSubstitutedGlyphsManually = false;
        CTFontRef runFont = CFDictionaryGetValue(CTRunGetAttributes(run), kCTFontAttributeName);

        // Determine if we need to draw substituted glyphs manually. Do so if the runFont is not the same as the overall font.
        if (self.dimsSubstitutedGlyphs && ![self.font isEqual:(UIFont *)runFont]) {
            drawSubstitutedGlyphsManually = true;
        }

        CFIndex runGlyphIndex = 0;
        for (; runGlyphIndex < runGlyphCount; runGlyphIndex++) {
            CFRange glyphRange = CFRangeMake(runGlyphIndex, 1);
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, -(glyphArcInfo[runGlyphIndex + glyphOffset].angle));

            // Center this glyph by moving left by half its width.
            CGFloat glyphWidth = glyphArcInfo[runGlyphIndex + glyphOffset].width;
            CGFloat halfGlyphWidth = glyphWidth / 2.0;
            CGPoint positionForThisGlyph = CGPointMake(textPosition.x - halfGlyphWidth, textPosition.y);

            // Glyphs are positioned relative to the text position for the line, so offset text position leftwards by this glyph's width in preparation for the next glyph.
            textPosition.x -= glyphWidth;

            CGAffineTransform textMatrix = CTRunGetTextMatrix(run);
            textMatrix.tx = positionForThisGlyph.x;
            textMatrix.ty = positionForThisGlyph.y;
            CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, textMatrix);

            CTRunDraw(run, context, glyphRange);
        }

        glyphOffset += runGlyphCount;
    }

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context,0.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    free(glyphArcInfo);
    CFRelease(line);    

}
```

As you can see i've use a **really not good** method for calculate the space between each caracter ( in the original example the space between characters are based also on the arc size). Anyway this seems to work almost fine.

The best solution could be to curve a rectangle ( so the linear text ), with graphics effort and less strange calculations.

This is what i've obtained
[image: sample result]

Hope it helps

Comment: I used some of your codes from here to make my control http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819787/how-to-make-equal-space-between-texts-in-the-circular-menu?noredirect=1#comment47773706_29819787  Now i want to make the equal space between each word. Can anybody help me to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Juggleware's solution works great, I can't seem to find a way to change the direction though, i.e. how would I go to move the arc from clockwise to counter-clockwise?

**Update**: After struggling for days with the overcomplicated code in that example, I decided to roll my own. I went for a declarative approach using CATextLayers which are placed on the circle and rotated individually. This way the results were much more simple to achieve. Here's the core code for you:

```
-(void)layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
    if ( layer != self.layer )
    {
        return;
    }

    self.layer.sublayers = nil;

    LOG( @"Laying out sublayers..." );

    CGFloat xcenter = self.frame.size.width / 2;
    CGFloat ycenter = self.frame.size.height / 2;

    float angle = arcStart;
    float angleStep = arcSize / [self.text length];

    for ( NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self.text length]; ++i )
    {
        NSRange range = { .location = i, .length = 1 };
        NSString* c = [self.text substringWithRange:range];

        CGFloat yoffset = sin( DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ) * radius;
        CGFloat xoffset = cos( DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ) * radius;

        CGFloat rotAngle = 90 - angle;

        if ( clockwise )
        {
            yoffset = -yoffset;
            rotAngle = -90 + angle;
        }

        CATextLayer* tl = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
        if ( debugMode )
        {
            tl.borderWidth = 1;
            tl.cornerRadius = 3;
            tl.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        }
        tl.frame = CGRectMake( shiftH + xcenter - xoffset, shiftV + ycenter + yoffset, 20, 20 );
        tl.font = self.font.fontName;
        tl.fontSize = self.font.pointSize;
        tl.foregroundColor = self.color.CGColor;
        tl.string = c;
        tl.alignmentMode = @"center";

        tl.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform( CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(rotAngle) ) );

        if ( debugMode )
        {
            CATextLayer* debugLayer = [self debugLayerWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u: %.0f°", i, angle]];
            debugLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform( CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-rotAngle) ) );
            [tl addSublayer:debugLayer];
        }        
        [self.layer addSublayer:tl];

        angle += angleStep;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "arcStart" variable represents?

Comment: arcStart is the offset (in degrees) where you want the curved text to start. By tweaking this property, you can change the alignment. In a subsequent version of this code, I'm honoring UITextAlignment and UIViewContentMode properties. I can post this code to github, if you're interested.

Comment: No need... Already created my own version based on your code. Thank you!

Comment: Tx for the code? I'm very interested to a github link (if possible)

Comment: @DrMickeyLauer Your approach looks much cleaner, especially considering it doesn't use all those odd CF arrays and structs. Can you post your latest example/code to github?

Comment: @fvisticot I put the original code on github at https://github.com/juggleware/CoreTextArcView_iOS Please contribute and help make it better!

Comment: The text seems blur out though, wondering why?  Getting more obvious when display on a Retina screen

Comment: @JapCon fix the blurry text on Retina with tl.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

Answer (score 3):

You can download a sample project that use CoreTextArcView: https://github.com/javenisme/CurvaView

Comment: This one works perfectly.  Just need to convert to ARC compatible for my need.

Comment: best as per required

Answer (score 1):

Take the circumference of the inner circle. This is the circle you want the base of the characters to be rendered onto. We'll call this circumference `totalLength`.

I assume you have a list of strings to render around the circle in `textItems`.

Take the width of each string into a `textWidths` array and distribute them evenly across `totalLength`, perhaps like this pseudo(pythonish) code:

```
block = max(textWidths)
assert(block * len(textWidths) <= totalLength)
offsets = [(block * i) + ((block-width) / 2) for i, width in enumerate(textWidths)]
```

Although better layouts can no doubt be done in the cases where the assert would trigger, all that really matters is that we know where individual words start and end in a known area. To render on a straight line of length `totalLength` we simply start rendering each block of text at `offsets[i]`.

To get it onto the circle, we'll map that straight line back onto the circumference. To do that we need to map each pixel along that line onto a position on the circle and an angle. This function converts the offset along that line into an angle (it takes values in the range 0 to `totalLength`)

```
def offsetToAngle(pixel):
    ratio = pixel / totalLength
    angle = math.pi * 2 * ratio # cool kids use radians.
    return angle
```

that's your angle. To get a position:

```
def angleToPosition(angle, characterWidth):
    xNorm = math.sin(angle + circleRotation)
    yNorm = math.cos(angle + circleRotation)

    halfCWidth = characterWidth / 2
    x = xNorm * radius + yNorm * halfCWidth # +y = tangent
    y = yNorm * radius - xNorm * halfCWidth # -x = tangent again.

    # translate to the circle centre
    x += circleCentre.x
    y += circleCentre.y

    return x,y
```

That's a bit more tricky. This is pretty much the crux of your issues, I'd have thought. The big deal is that you need to offset back along the tangent of the circle to work out the point to start rendering so that the middle of the character hits the radius of the circle. What constitues 'back' depends on your coordinate system. if 0,0 is in the bottom left, then the signs of the tangent components is swapped. I assumed top left.

*This is important:* I'm also making a big assumption that the text rotation occurs around the bottom left of the glyph. If it doesn't then things will look a bit weird. It will be more noticeable at larger font sizes. There is always a way to compensate for wherever it rotates around, and there's usually a way to tell the system where you want the rotation origin to be (that will be related to the `CGContextTranslateCTM` call in your code I'd imagine) you'll need to do a small experiment to get characters drawing at a single point rotating around their bottom left.

`circleRotation` is just an offset so you can rotate the whole circle, rather than having things always be in the same orientation. That's in radians too.

so now for each character in each block of text:

```
for text, offset in zip(textItems, offsets):
    pix = offset # start each block at the offset we calculated earlier.
    for c in text:
        cWidth = measureGlyph(c)
        # choose the circumference location of the middle of the character
        # this is to match with the tangent calculation of tangentToOffset
        angle = offsetToAngle(pix + cWidth / 2)
        x,y = angleToPosition(angle, cWidth)
        drawGlyph(c, x, y, angle)

        pix += cWidth # start of next character in circumference space
```

That's the concept, anyway.

Comment: of course if you can draw and rotate a glyph from its bottom middle then you don't need the tangent stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface CircleTextCell : NSCell {

}

@end

#import "CircleTextCell.h"

#define PI (3.141592653589793)

@implementation CircleTextCell

- (void)drawWithFrame: (NSRect)cellFrame inView: (NSView*)controlView
{
    NSAttributedString *str = [self attributedStringValue];
    NSSize stringSize = [str size];
    NSUInteger chars = [[str string] length];
    CGFloat radius = (stringSize.width + 5 * chars) / (2 * PI);
    CGFloat diameter = 2*radius;
    NSPoint scale = {1,1};
    if (diameter > cellFrame.size.width)
    {
        scale.x = cellFrame.size.width / diameter;
    }
    if (diameter > cellFrame.size.height)
    {
        scale.y = cellFrame.size.height / diameter;
    }
    NSAffineTransform *transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
    NSAffineTransformStruct identity = [transform transformStruct];
    [transform scaleXBy: scale.x yBy: scale.y];
    [transform translateXBy: radius yBy: 0];
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

    [transform concat];

    NSPoint origin = {0,0};
    CGFloat angleScale = 360 / (stringSize.width + (5 * chars));
    for (NSUInteger i=0 ; i<chars ; i++)
    {
        NSAttributedString *substr = 
            [str attributedSubstringFromRange: NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
        [substr drawAtPoint: origin];
        [transform setTransformStruct: identity];
        CGFloat displacement = [substr size].width + 5;
        [transform translateXBy: displacement yBy: 0];
        [transform rotateByDegrees: angleScale * displacement];
        [transform concat];
    }
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
@end

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class CircleTextCell;
@interface CircleTextView : NSView {
    CircleTextCell *cell;
}

@end

#import "CircleTextView.h"
#import "CircleTextCell.h"

@implementation CircleTextView
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = 
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSFont fontWithName: @"Zapfino"
                                                            size:32]
                                    forKey: NSFontAttributeName];
    NSAttributedString *str =
        [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"Hello World!  This is a very long text string that will be wrapped into a circle by a cell drawn in a custom view"
                                        attributes: attributes];
    cell = [[CircleTextCell alloc] init];
    [cell setAttributedStringValue: str];
}
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect 
{
    [[NSColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect: rect];
    [cell drawWithFrame: [self bounds] inView: self];
}

@end
```

Comment: Could you provide an elliptic curve text ios demo, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]that is the best url https://github.com/javenisme/CurvaView to set curve your text:

But as per the the degree wise curve i just update a code little bit and we can set the curve as a degree wise . like 45,60,90 180, 360.

Look at the code : https://github.com/tikamsingh/CurveTextWithAngle

You can take some idea.

Comment: Yes i mentioned your url . but if you look a code then u understand what i modified on that. I agreed using your framework. but this is little bit enhancement.

Answer (score -1):

Referring to [**Ali Seyman**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15656369/2431627):

> You can download a sample project that use CoreTextArcView: https://github.com/javenisme/CurvaView

Add on this method to reduce the view frame size, just like UILabel.

```
- (void)sizeToFit{
[super sizeToFit];

CGFloat width = ceilf( fabsf((self.radius*2)) + self.font.lineHeight) + 3.0;
CGRect f = self.frame;
f.size = CGSizeMake(width,width);
self.frame = f;
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

If anyone could improve on reducing the height as well, welcome to add on.