# iOS animation (transition) for text appearing in wave

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to make "After app. 2 seconds, the text appears in a smooth wave from left to right".

Has anyone some code for this wave of text or some solution?

Comment: I need animation (transition) for text appearing in wave.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Core Graphics to render text along a UIBezierPath.
This question - [Curve text on existing circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841642/curve-text-on-existing-circle) - illustrates how to accomplish this very well. Hope this helps!