# Display text in a cuved format

Tags: ios, text-rendering

I am looking to draw some text in curved format. It doesn't matter which control I use: `UITextField`, `UILabel` or `UITextView`.

I just want to show text something like shown in the image

[image]

Still looking for solution.
Please help ?

Comment: Is your text fixed? Or its dynamic?

Comment: It is dynamic. User can change it later

Answer (score -1):

[Check out this link](https://nodeload.github.com/yllan/funtextfield/zipball/master). Though this is for mac, i think you can port it for ios

ABOVE LINK IS OUT DATED. PLEASE FIND YOUR SOLUTION FROM [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22655562/1357774)

Other thing I can think is not an easy way out. Take a string as an array of letters, Take labels for each later and rotate each label to some angle that is calculated to create an arc for your text. Second approach need more manipulation and logic :) All the best.

Comment: The second approach will not work for dynamic text (Or it is very hard to implement) and first one is also not suitable I have gone through both of them before posting this question.

Comment: First only I said its not easy, since you need to create an array of letters and then calculate and then Rotate it. Else you wont find any ready made material for this :(