# iPhone iOS is it possible to render a UIView curved?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, core-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Showing curved text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792948/showing-curved-text)

I have a UIView witha  UILabel on it. How can I use renderInContext and other graphical operations to make the UIView appear curved, as in the example below?

[image: curved text]

Comment: I used a UILabel as an example, but need to know how to render ANY UIView curved, not just draw curved text :/

Answer (score 0):

The following Core Text tutorial has exactly the same example that you need.

http://invasivecode.tumblr.com/core-text