# Curve Text In UILabel Programmatically Around UIButton

Tags: text, uibutton, uilabel

I have created a circular UIButton by setting the cornerRadius property to half of the width and height values of the UIButton.

```
btn.layer.cornerRadius = 75.f;
```

That works fine but I would like to also create a label for the UIButton where the label text curves around the edge of the UIButton.

If this is even possible could somebody post a snippet of code as to how this curved text around the button edge could be accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have a look at this question: [Curve text on existing circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841642/curve-text-on-existing-circle)

It's not actually a UIButton, but you will certainly get an idea of how to draw text on a curve.

There's especially talk of the sample project [CoreTextArcCocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreTextArcCocoa/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple. It's for OS X instead for iOS, but you might want to check this out.

Comment: thanks.  I searched for "Curved text on circle" but that didn't appear in the list.