# iOS: How to draw text curving along a UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, uibezierpath

I need to programmatically draw something like this:-

[image: curved text following a bezierpath line]
<sub>(source: [planetclegg.com](http://www.planetclegg.com/projects/images/SomeTextWarpedToACurve.png))</sub>

Except that my UIBezierPath is closed & I need the text to fit inside it while following the curve.  I have my path drawing correctly, the problem is the text. I've searched the 'net and read a bunch of tutorials but nothing seems to provide a solution.  Is this possible in iOS, and if so how is it done?  Links to relevant tutorials and/or code snippets would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the sample code in my [Github](https://github.com/skyhacker2/iOS-Core-Graphics-Test), the `ArcText`.

Answer (score 0):

Someone just pointed me to this, which appears to answer my question: [Curve text on existing circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841642/curve-text-on-existing-circle)

My apologies for the duplication.

Comment: This is an old thread, but I'm doing some research. Your original question was about how to draw text along an arbitrary Bezier. Your self-answer is a link to a page that illustrates how to wrap text around a circle, which is a simpler problem. Did you find a solution to drawing text along a bezier path?