# Draw text along elliptical path in Swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift

How to draw curved text inside an elliptical path. The circle is easy but elliptical too hard for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948258/ios-how-to-draw-text-curving-along-a-uibezierpath ?

Comment: Quick searching finds this (not mine): https://medium.com/swlh/add-curved-text-in-your-app-3d41d4463c24 ... might be just what you're looking for.

Comment: Believe, these [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771864/draw-text-along-circular-path-in-swift-for-ios) is useful for you =)