# How to make curved text of UILabel Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I want to make curved text Of `UILabel` . How to do implement this ?

[image]

My label code till now is :

```
UILabel *loveLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
loveLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, 50, 50);
loveLabel.text = @"Flowers";
loveLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
loveLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
loveLabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview:loveLabel];
```

Comment: Somebody already asked similar question I hope it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841642/curve-text-on-existing-circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can download a sample project that use CoreTextArcView:
```

[github](https://github.com/javenisme/CurvaView)

import "CoreTextArcView.h" & add code in viewdidload

```
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(0, 120, 320, 120);
UIFont * font1 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:26.0f];
UIColor * color1 = [UIColor whiteColor];
CoreTextArcView * cityLabel = [[[CoreTextArcView alloc] initWithFrame:rect1
                                                                font:font1
                                                                text:@"New York City"
                                                              radius:85
                                                             arcSize:110
                                                               color:color1] autorelease];
cityLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake(0, 235, 320, 200);
CoreTextArcView * cityLabel2 = [[[CoreTextArcView alloc] initWithFrame:rect2
                                                                 font:font1
                                                                 text:@"Google"
                                                               radius:-80
                                                              arcSize:-80
                                                                color:color1] autorelease];

[cityLabel2 showsLineMetrics];
cityLabel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[self.view addSubview:cityLabel];
[self.view addSubview:cityLabel2];
```

Comment: This will circle my UILabel view . I need to curve the text like the image which i have provided in question.

Comment: Can you give an example .As not able to implement CoreTextArcView

Comment: download coretextarcview & add two coretextarcview file then add code