# how to make Curve TEXT in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, text, uitextview

How to make curve text in IOS objective-c
existing answer similar curve text in upper part but I wanna it in lower part as in image.

[image: CURVE TEXT]

Comment: Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841642/curve-text-on-existing-circle

Comment: Visit this link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841642/curve-text-on-existing-circle>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    - (UIImage*) createMenuRingWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    CGRect imageSize = CGRectMake(0,0,300,300);
    float perSectionDegrees = 360 / [sections count];
    float totalRotation = 90;
    char* fontName = (char*)[self.menuItemsFont.fontName cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, imageSize.size.width, imageSize.size.height, 8, 4 * imageSize.size.width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextSelectFont(context, fontName, 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);

    CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(imageSize.size.width / 2, imageSize.size.height / 2);
    double radius = (frame.size.width / 2);

    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(centerPoint.x - (frame.size.width / 2), centerPoint.y - (frame.size.height / 2), frame.size.width, frame.size.height));

    for (int index = 0; index < [sections count]; index++)
    {
        NSString* menuItemText = [sections objectAtIndex:index];
        CGSize textSize = [menuItemText sizeWithFont:self.menuItemsFont];
        char* menuItemTextChar = (char*)[menuItemText cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        float x = centerPoint.x + radius * cos(degreesToRadians(totalRotation));
        float y = centerPoint.y + radius * sin(degreesToRadians(totalRotation));

        CGContextSaveGState(context);

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, x, y);
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, degreesToRadians(totalRotation - 90));
        CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 0 - (textSize.width / 2), 0 - (textSize.height / 2), menuItemTextChar, strlen(menuItemTextChar));

        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        totalRotation += perSectionDegrees;
    }

    CGImageRef contextImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:contextImage];
}
```

I HAVE TRIED IT FROM THIS LINK AND IT WORKED
[Curve text on existing circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841642/curve-text-on-existing-circle)

Answer (score 0):

We make sample app for this
Checkout this app : https://github.com/tikamsingh/CurveTextWithAngle

Answer (score -1):

There is no built-in way to achieve that. If I were you, I'd render the text in a regular text view, and then apply Core Image or `GPUImage` transforms/filters on that view's bitmap representation. But it's an advanced-level task so if you are new to iOS, I'd recommend becoming more familiar with the platform before diving into advanced image manipulation techniques.

Bottomline: It's possible but there's no straightforward/easy way.

Comment: it's text with shadow not image .

Comment: @sumitrathore so? my solution still applies exactly the way I've told.

Comment: i wanna rotate UILabel and your answer is about image rotation @Can Poyrazoğlu

Comment: @sumitrathore, he is talking about rotating the text view's bitmap representation.

Comment: @sumitrathore as I've *clearly* stated in my answer: ` I'd render the text in a regular text view`. to manipulate the text, you need to apply a filter by rendering it into a bitmap. I obviously know that it's a UILabel/UITextView or whatever.