# Creating Rounded UILabel in Swift

Tags: swift, uilabel

I am attempting to create a rounded UILabel similar to the below image.

[image]

I am using the following code that only changing the rounded corner of the label.I wondering how to achieve a rounded label similar to above image and i also tried to achieve the rounded label using CGAffineTranfrom function but it only changing the angle of the label. someone,Please point me the direction..

```
 @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   label.layer.cornerRadius = self.label.frame.width/2
   label.layer.masksToBounds = true
 //label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(currentValue) // UISlider Value

}
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841642/curve-text-on-existing-circle

Comment: You're looking for the wrong thing, and it's more complex than you're hoping: Google: core text arc