# How to draw Multiline Text parallel to arc in pie chart?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am having wheel of fortune (pie chart) drawn using UIBezierPath. I want to draw multiline text in every pie parallel to arc.

Please suggest your ideas.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841642/curve-text-on-existing-circle